# Is there a way to throttle logging in Java and information about the # of throttled messages?

Tags: java, logging, logback, log4j2

I have an application which when running into an unreachable external service will have to send a **lot** of data back into the previous queue, and would generate two log messages for each message rejected that way.

Now, I want those messages, especially if they happen during normal operation. But if the remote service dies entirely I might seen hundreds or thousands of these until the service stops attempting the connection. I could optimize that, but this made me think of a different question:

I know I can use a throttling filter in either `logback` or `log4j2` to reduce the raw log spam. But is there a way, either with those two frameworks or with another one, to then get "meta information" about how many messages were throttled the next time one is sent to the log again?